# How can I register a user in Next.js 14 with a Strapi backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

I'm currently working on a project in Next.js 14, and the client has requested that I connect the backend to Strapi. Since it's my first time doing this, I wasn't sure how to proceed. The client specifically asked me to send fetch requests to the backend. I've decided to ask for your opinions on the best approaches to connect to the relevant backend. Nevertheless, I still want to share my own approach.

`your text`

```
try {
        const response = await fetch('Base URL/api/auth/local/register', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer Token`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: userNameValue,
            email: valueEmail,
            password: valuePassword
          })
        })
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        if (response.ok) {
        // your codes...
        } else {
          console.log('An error occurred:', data.message || 'Something went wrong!')
          toast.error(data.error.message, {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
          })
        }`your text`
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error)
        toast.error(error.message, {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
        })
      }
```

`your text`

Comment: Is there something not working with your code? And if so, can you post the relevant errors? Strapi has an extensive documentation that also contains many examples. So maybe, take a gander [there](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/intro) before asking here.